# State Picker more prone to key strokes?

Tags: jquery, html

Is there a way I can make it this state picker will recognize the state you want to pick by entered key strokes. Like if you press the keys 'flo' it would jump to Florida. I've seen more than a few websites have this feature so I would like to do this too.

```html
<div class="input-group mb-3">
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text">State</span>
            <select class="form-control" id="state2" name="state2">
                <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
                <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
                <option value="CA">California</option>
                <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
                <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
                <option value="DC">District of Columbia</option>
                <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
                <option value="FL">Florida</option>
                <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
                <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
                <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
                <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
                <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
                <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
                <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
                <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
                <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
                <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
                <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
                <option value="ME">Maine</option>
                <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
                <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
                <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
                <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
                <option value="MT">Montana</option>
                <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
                <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
                <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
                <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
                <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
                <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
                <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
                <option value="NY">New York</option>
                <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
                <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
                <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
                <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
                <option value="PR">Puerto Rico</option>
                <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
                <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
                <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
                <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
                <option value="TX">Texas</option>
                <option value="UT">Utah</option>
                <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
                <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
                <option value="WA">Washington</option>
                <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
                <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
                <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8bw0jcpu/

Comment: Can you please show your efforts doing this?

Comment: Look into using a type ahead plugin

Comment: Can you describe what the problem you're having is?  What you've described is exactly how a `select` (or drop down list) works already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using  [typeahead.js jQuery plugin](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md)

> When initializing a typeahead using the typeahead.js jQuery plugin,
>   you pass the plugin method one or more datasets. The source of a
>   dataset is responsible for computing a set of suggestions for a given
>   query.

Check below example :

```js
var substringMatcher = function(strs) {
  return function findMatches(q, cb) {
    var matches, substringRegex;

    // an array that will be populated with substring matches
    matches = [];

    // regex used to determine if a string contains the substring `q`
    substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');

    // iterate through the pool of strings and for any string that
    // contains the substring `q`, add it to the `matches` array
    $.each(strs, function(i, str) {
      if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
        matches.push(str);
      }
    });

    cb(matches);
  };
};

var states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California',
  'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii',
  'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana',
  'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota',
  'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire',
  'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota',
  'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island',
  'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont',
  'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'
];

$('#the-basics .typeahead').typeahead({
  hint: true,
  highlight: true,
  minLength: 1
},
{
  name: 'states',
  source: substringMatcher(states)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.bundle.js"></script>

<label>Select State</label>
<div id="the-basics">
  <input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="States of USA" class="form-control">
</div>
```